# HP ENVY TouchSmart 15t-j000 Quad Edition + custom mSata Plextor M5M 64GB SSD

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, ssd

The ssd did not come along with the laptop, so i bought one myself and physically installed it.

I've booted into Ubuntu from a USB drive and my goal is to install / and /home in the SSD. (because most of the actual media exists on the HDD)

The only problem is i'm unable to detect the SSD while configuring the partitions.

I know the SSD is not the problem because it recognizes in a different laptop.

I've followed the instructions shown in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI but that still doesn't help in identifying the SSD partition.

Any help would be appreciated.

(p.s: I'm wondering if i have to prepare the SSD through windows or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same machine and getting Linux to run on it has not been plug-and-play.

Is the issue that the drive is not detected by the machine, or it will not boot from the drive?

If the drive is not detected, then double-check your connection or try a different drive. That sounds like a hardware issue to me.

In regards to the latter question, a few tips to get Linux (Ubuntu 13.04 for me) to boot:

- Ensure legacy mode is ON
- Make sure that partition is "bootable" (use gParted)

Kind of random, but if you keep trying to boot and you end up at a black screen, try turning the brightness of the screen up!

Best of luck!